# Using bundle exec may solve this?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, bundler

Here is my `Gemfile`

```
source :rubygems

gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'activerecord', '3.0.9'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.12.2'
gem 'logger'
gem 'nokogiri'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rack-test'
  gem 'ruby-debug19'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

I run `rake console` which works in other projects and now I get this message:

`You have already activated activesupport 3.1.3, but your Gemfile requires activesupport 3.0.9. Using bundle exec may solve this.`

How do I use `bundle exec to solve this? What does it mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run `bundle exec rake console` which means that the command (in this case `rake console`) will be locked to the specific gems listed in your Gemfile.

Comment: Note that in some versions of rvm, `bundle exec ` is necessary, and in some, it's automatic. I think that was a convenience that they added for a while, and then took back out because it was causing problems.

Answer (score 41):

To stop using `bundle exec rake` you can run `bundle clean --force`. This command will update your Gemfile.lock.

Comment: This works! Much better than the bundle exec workaround

Answer (score 7):

rubygems-bundler solves this. Run the following commands:

`$ gem install rubygems-bundler`
`$ $ gem regenerate_binstubs`

Then try your bundle again.

Comment: this worked for me and imo best answer that works without making any changes to your existing Gemfile and Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

You can check to make sure that you include `rake` in your Gemfile. If it's not, add it, and specify the version "you already activated".

or you can just update it on your local like

```
bundle update rake
```

I hope that this helps